# Overwrite Cast Operator in C++

Tags: c++, string, boost, syntax, casting

As a C++ beginner I want to write some simple type casts. It there a way to create casting logic which can be used in the `type new = (type)old` format with the prefix parentheses?

```
string Text = "Hello";
char* Chars = "Goodbye";
int Integer = 42;

string Message = Text + (string)Integer + (string)Chars + "!";
```

I'd like to stick with this syntax if possible. For example the string cast of boost `int Number = boost::lexical_cast<int>("Hello World")` has an unattractive long syntax.

Comment: `(int)Chars` and `(char*)Integer` already have specific meanings that are completely unrelated to what you want them to mean.

Comment: What's wrong with boost::lexical_cast<int>(..)? I doubt you can get much terser than this unless you pull the function into the local namespace via a using statement. Even then I don't see the value, you want to be clear in what your code is doing and lexical_cast is understood, common and clear.

Comment: I would really advice against using another syntax. The complexity of the newer casts are there for a reason and even if you would define them to other symbols it would only make your code hard to read for anyone else but yourself. Getting used to the syntax used by everyone else is the way to go in the long run

Comment: In your example, C++11 lets you write `std::to_string(Integer)`. The other cast works already.

Comment: @Bo Persson. `to_string` works fine. You say the others work already. Then how to convert `string` to `char*`? I want to do it in one line, like `char* Text = ("Hello Number " + to_string(8) + "!")`.

Comment: You can't do that in a single line, beause you have to store the characters somewhere. But you can get a `const char*` from `Message` by using `Message.c_str()`. It returns a pointer to a C string (which remains valid until `Message` changes the next time).

Comment: @Bo Persson. Please check out my solution using `strcpy` updated to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a normal function that you overload for different types:

```
std::string str(int i) {
   return "an integer";
}

std::string str(char* s) {
   return std::string(s);
}
```

Then use if not like a cast, but as a normal function call:

```
string Message = Text + str(Integer) + str(Chars) + "!";
```

Comment: With C++11 you already have `std::to_string(Integer)` in the standard library.

Answer (score 1):

It's the most common thing in C++ to cast using a `NAME<TYPE>(ARGUMENT)` syntax, like in `static_cast<int>(char)`. It makes sense to extend this the way boost does.

However, if you want to convert non-primitive types, you can use non-explicit constructors with a single argument and the cast operator.

```
class MyType {
  public:
    MyType(int); // cast from int
    operator int() const; // cast to int
};
```

This is not possible if you are dealing with already existing types.

You cannot change the behaviour of the C-style cast. C++ will make up its mind how to interpret such a cast.

You *could* however come up with an intermediate type that shortens the syntax:

```
template <typename From>
struct Cast {
  From from;
  Cast(From const& from) : from(from) {}
  template <typename To>
  operator To() const {
    return convert(from,To());
  }
};

template <typename From>
Cast<From> cast(From const& from) {
  return Cast<From>(from);
};

std::string convert(int, std::string const&);
```

This would allow you to convert things explicitly but without stating how exactly:

```
int i = 7;
std::string s = cast(i);
```